# Pass Dynamic Value in Html anchor tag using Python Django in Jinja Template

Tags: python, django, jinja2, sandbox, cuckoo

I am working on Cuckoo Sandbox and I hope that everyone will understand my question as It is going difficult for me to explain the question. I am working on different files and I am facing some issues. The issue is that I want to call dynamic variable in html anchor tag in Django, but, when I pass the dynamic variable the sidebar disappears automatically. Also I am working on Jinja template. I need your help guys:

urls.py file:

```
url(r"^(?P<task_id>\d+)/$", AnalysisRoutes.redirect_default, name="analysis/redirect_default"),
```

routes.py file:

```
@staticmethod
    def redirect_default(request, task_id):
        if not isinstance(task_id, (unicode, str)):
            task_id = str(task_id)

        return redirect(reverse(
            "analysis",
            args=(re.sub(r"\^d+", "", task_id), "summary")),
            permanent=False
        )
```

include.html file:

```
<li>
                <a href="{% url 'analysis/redirect_default'  45 %}">
                    <div class="parent-icon"><i class='bx bx-home'></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-title">Summary</div>
                </a>
            </li>
```

In HTML file you can see that there is a int number 45. Just need to parse task_id dynamic value in html anchor tag. When I pass task_id variable in replace of 45 the sidebar disappears automatically. Kindly help me to resolve this issue. Thank you

[When we pass static Id the Sidebar remains appears and nothing change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7JWd.jpg)

But when I pass dynamic data or without any Id the sidebar disappears as explained in figure 2:

[without any Id or when pass dynamic data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGboy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try [get_absolute_url()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) instead of hard coding.

```
from django.urls import reverse
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('analysis', kwargs={'id' : self.id})

<a href="{{ analysis.get_absolute_url }}">{{ analysis.data}}</a>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. It gives an error

Comment: Show us your trouble.

Comment: dear @ttt, I have updated my question with image kindly review it. And on the console side It shows no error.

Comment: kindly review it plx I have added the pics in my question

Comment: I see that this is an old question, and I have also been away for a while. Upload a picture of what the error looks like when you implement the code from my above answer.

Comment: Dear @ttt, when I implements your code my sidebar disappears. Here is the Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGboy.jpg

Comment: Are you using a `for loop` in the `include.html` file?

Comment: No. I am not using for loop and if u have no issue then I can include.html file

Comment: Ok if u want. Try to describe all details.